# pscp upload using vbs

Tags: vbscript, pscp

I am attempting to create a function in VBScript that uploads a text file to a remote server using the `pscp` command.  When I run the function, I receive the error

> 80070002 - The system cannot find the file specified.

Below is the function, I was wondering if there was an issue with the `pscp` command or if there was an alternative way to upload a file in VBScript.

```
Function upload(source, dest)
    WScript.Echo source
    Set system = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    system.Run "pscp -batch -pw [PASSWORD HERE] " & source & " [USERNAME HERE]:" & dest, 0, True
    WScript.Echo "....Finished " & vbCrlf
End Function
```

Comment: Does the source path contain spaces? What are the values of `source` and `dest` anyway?

Comment: The source path does not contain spaces, and the values source and dest are the source paths from the local and remote servers that are passed into the function.  I have tried plugging the paths directly into the function with the same results.

Comment: *\*sigh\** Do I speak Swahili or something? What are the values of `source` and `dest`? Do not paraphrase. You may obfuscate individual folder names if necessary, but keep the structure intact.

Comment: @Kein Thiel Check location of pscp program or specify full path on script